# MVC3 - Model to HTML table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

I have an OfferingCategoriesViewModel which contains a list of OfferingCategoryModel's.

How I can display each OfferingCategoryModel in my view so it looks like below

[image: http://imgur.com/8fsEg]

Note: Ideally I want the number of models to display per row to be included in the OfferingCategoriesViewModel.

I currently have this:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (Spice.TimeBank.Models.Category.OfferingCategoryModel category in Model.ListOfCategories)
            {
                <td>@category.Descripton</td>
            }
            -->
            @for (int i = item.Count(); i < 5; i++)
            {
                <td></td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Why create a partial view for each model? They are the same model. And what is the problem with creating the table? Where are you stuck?

Comment: hi @Mert the problem is how to create a row of X models

Answer (score 0):

I know you are describing the use of tables for that layout, but I would actually recommend going for `<div>` blocks with a layout using css `float: left;`, to get an self-arranging layout depending on user screen resolution and window size.

That way you avoid having to worry about how many columns to display, and the html and styles becomes cleaner.

In fact, if you design it that way, you can just create a single MVC [`DisplayTemplate`](http://jacob.steelsmith.org/content/display-templates-partial-views-mvc-3-using-razor)  rendering each div for that model, and have MVC worry about iterating through your items.

EDIT:
[Here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0405.htm) you can find more info on how to use `float`:
The 4th tutorial might be of special interest, since it shows an example of a layout nearly identical to yours.

Also [here's](http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_float.html) another very good source of good info using floating elements, with visual examples as well.

Comment: what so create each "cell" as a seperate <div> element?

Comment: Correct, have each of those elements representing categories be a separate <div>, with a fixed size, and have them self-arrange. Check this out for more info on using float: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0405.htm
I forgot to include the link on my original response. I'll add it now.
The 4th tutorial might be of help. The layout you are after is somewhat similar to what an image gallery might look like.